# Can i split my yaml file into multiple yaml file and import in single one?

Tags: node.js

> I want to split my yaml file and import in one single file . i want to make seprate yaml file of every route and import in single file.

Comment: Some YAML parsers support the `!include` directive.

Comment: I still confuse to understand the structure of yaml file